# Improving Functionality of Map Creator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My code currently reads in a string (made of numbers `0`-`9`) and uses that value to blit a tile to the screen in a corresponding array. Since I use numbers it's easy to slice the string to get one character and cast that value to an int to use it as a index, e.g.:

```
display.blit(tiles[int(slicedString), rect])
```

Since I use this method, I can only have 10 elements in the tiles array (because I cant slice a number like `10`). Can anyone think of a way around this to get, let's say, 20 elements in the tile array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that e.g. hexadecimal uses `'a'` for `10`, `'b'` for `11`, and so on, just use letters for numbers beyond `9`:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j
```

One advantage of this is that [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) in Python already implements this for `base`s beyond `10`:

```
>>> int('a', 20)
10
>>> int('j', 20)
19
>>> int('hi', 20)
358
```

which simplifies your implementation.

Comment: Can you explain the second argument in `int("hi", 20)` And could you give me a test case for int("1", 20). Would that just return 1?

Comment: @JGerulskis as I mention, and per the documentation I've linked to, it's the `base`. For example, `int(s, 16)` would convert to integer assuming `s` is in hexadecimal representation.

Comment: @JGerulskis seriously? Why don't you try it and find out?! Or just think about it - what's `1` in binary? In octal? In hexadecimal?